# Find the greatest right number from the current number in the array algorithm

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, big-o

My algorithm should find the **greatest** right number from the *current* number in an input `array`, for example, given the following `int[]` input:

> 5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 2

My algorithm will output:

> 9, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2

Here is my current code:

```
public static int[] FindGreatestRightNumber(int[] input)
{
    var output = new int[input.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        int maxRightNumber = (i == input.Length - 1 ? input[i] : 0);

        for (var j = i+1; j < input.Length; j++)
        {
            var currentNumber = input[j];
            if (maxRightNumber < currentNumber)
                maxRightNumber = currentNumber;
        }
        output[i] = maxRightNumber;
    }

    return output;
}
```

I was told it could be much faster, how? any idea?

**UPDATE:** Please don't use `LINQ` in your answers, I would like to get familiar with faster ways to solve the problem using **simple code**, no `LINQ`, `IEnumerable` Extension Methods etc.

Comment: @Saen: The algorthm is: `For each input number, output the greatest of the *following* numbers, or output the input number if there are no following numbers.`, at least according to the example given.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why there's no `5` in the output sequence.  Given that corrected algorithm I'm not sure it *could* be much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a single pass from the right hand side. The trick is realizing *maxRightVal(n) = max(maxRightVal(n+1), values(n+1))*:

```
var output = new int[input.Length];
output[input.Length-1] = input[input.Length-1];

for(int i = input.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    output[i] = output[i+1] > input[i+1] ? output[i+1] : input[i+1];
```

Comment: @Lc. What is the _n_ in your formula?

Comment: @YairNevet The element index

Comment: @lc. It would be accurate to say that my code is _O(n^2)_ and your code is _O(n)_ ?

Answer (score 2):

very simple if you want to skip some items and search the max

```
int[]arr = {5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 2};
int currentIndex = 2;
int currentValue = 6;
int max = arr.Skip(currentIndex).Where(f => f > currentValue).Max();
```

**EDIT** if you want to simply sort an array, then:

```
   int[] sorted = arr.OrderByDescending();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just using [`Enumerable.Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292667.aspx) method?

> Returns the maximum value in a sequence of Int32 values.

```
int[] input = new int[] { 5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 2 };
int biggest = input.Max();
Console.WriteLine(biggest); // 9
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/htgUNo)**.

Since, I see the question better now, VLad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289655/447156) looks the right one.

Comment: He wants the max number to the right of each number. Vlad's answer is closer to be being correct.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the (n-2)th elements, maintain a current max array which is initialised with nth element. Keep updating it if the current element is greater than the element in max array. Continue this until the first element is reached.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the largest value to the right of each element;

```
 int[] input = {5, 9, 6, 1, 3, 2};
 int[] output = input
            .Take(input.Length-1)
            .Select( (x,i) => input.Skip(i+1).Max()).ToArray();
```